# Combo box item selection based combo box

Tags: wpf

I have a combo box having four items.

If I select a first item then second combo box must show some item with respect to the selection of first combo box item . If I select the second item then the second combo box must show some item .

Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Can you put some code which you tried and also justify your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 combo box in XAML file:

```
    <ComboBox Name="cbTest1" SelectionChanged="cbTest1_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="3"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox Name="cbTest2" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
```

In function cbTest1_SelectionChanged as per selected value you can set value in the variable data

```
  private void cbTest1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> oData = new List<string>();
        if (((ComboBoxItem)cbTest1.SelectedValue).Content.ToString() == "1")
        {                
            oData.Add("DataType1_1");
            oData.Add("DataType1_2");
            oData.Add("DataType1_3");
            oData.Add("DataType1_4");                
        }
        else if (((ComboBoxItem)cbTest1.SelectedValue).Content.ToString() == "2")
        {                
            oData.Add("DataType2_1");
            oData.Add("DataType2_2");
            oData.Add("DataType2_3");
            oData.Add("DataType2_4");                
        }

        viewModel.Data = oData;
    }
```

Comment: Hi ,I am a beginner to Programming  i want step by step to understand the concept.

Comment: I think you are confused with binding, if you are not familiar with binding then you can directly set ItemSource in code.

Remove ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" from XAML, and instead of "viewModel.Data = oData;" use "cbTest2.ItemSource = oData;"